# O.D.E Integrating Factor Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I've been doing alright so far, but I can't seem to find the special integrating factor for this question, and Wolfram, as well as Symbolab, are unable to help. Please let me know:

$$(2x^2y + x)dy + (xy^2 + y)dx = 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrating factor is $1/(xy^2).$  If you multiply through by that, the equation becomes exact.

To find this factor, assume an integrating factor of the form $\mu(xy).$

Comment: I'm still struggling to actually do the steps after that, for some reason.

Comment: Also, why can we assume the form?

Comment: There are various tests to see what form the i.f. could be.  One checks to see if $(N_x - M_y)/(xM-yM)$ is a function of $xy$ alone. If so, you have a i.f. of that form.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2x^2y + x)dy + (xy^2 + y)dx = 0$$
Rearrange terms:
$$dxy+2x^2ydy + xy^2 dx = 0$$
$$dxy+(xy)(2xdy + y dx )= 0$$
Divide by $(xy)^2$
$$\dfrac {d(xy)}{(xy)^2}+\left(2\dfrac {dy}y + \dfrac { dx}x \right )= 0$$
Integrate.
$$\dfrac 1{xy}-\ln |xy^2|=C$$